# laravel testing requires multiple databases trying to use sqlite duplicate tables

Tags: laravel, sqlite, testing, phpunit

My testing journey continues...

In an app I have multiple databases 1. which is for the backend content with users for the back end and other stuff 2. the front end and users for the front end.

To carry out a test I need to create a user for the front end and test against content in the backend.

I'm trying to configure Phpunit and laravel to use two databases in memory using sqlite and I'm struggling.

I have two migration files for each database and have my normal set up as follows in `database.php`

```
'sqlite_testing_memory' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

in my `phpunit.xml` I have created the following:

```
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite_testing_memory"/>
    <env name="DB_DEFAULT" value="sqlite_testing_memory" />
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE_2" value=":memory:"/>
```

Each time I try and migrate the databases I get conflicts due to tables already existing e.g `users` from the back end conflicting with `users` from the front end.

I understand I can use `Schema::connection->('connection_name')` to specify the connection in the migration file but still get the conflicts.

Is it possible to have multiple databases in an sqlite in memory.

How can I get my tests to use multiple databases or should I consider reverting to a mysql testing database?

Help appreciated

**Edit**
I tried removing the duplicate tables so migrations work BUT I now have an error with the model connections.

Models have a connection attribute set to point them to the right connection - a test I am trying to run is now coming up with the error: `Unknown database ':memory:'` - this is relating to a model that relies on the second database connection

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this one?